# Javascript logic not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

The `if` condition is not working while the `else if` and `else` are working:

```js
function userchk() {
  var un = $('#user_name').val();
  if (un.length < 3 && un.length != 0) {
    $("#validateUser").html("<span style='color:red' class='status-not-available'>User Name Shoul Be Greater Then 3.</span>");
  }
  else if (un.length == 0) {
    $('#validationUser').html("<span style='color:red' class='status-not-available'> User Name Cannot Be Empty.</span>");
  }
  else {
    $('#validationUser').html("");
  }
}

$('#btnTest').on('click', function() {
  userchk();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnTest">Test userchk()</button>

<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" onBlur="userchk()" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
<div id="validationUser"></div>
```

Comment: what is `un` here?

Comment: it is a variable name var un =$('#user_name').val();

Comment: I will rather ask what is the value of `un`. What will it log if you do `console.log(un)`

Comment: please post a complete code (with `user_name`, `validateUser` element).

Comment: `"#validateUser" !== "#validationUser"`

Comment: check now......

Comment: @Andreas what????

Comment: Check your selectors

Comment: @brk console.log(un) says correct value tht i input

Comment: @MritunjayPathak is it a string or number?

Comment: @brk The script works. It's just a wrong selector...

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition results in an element with id **#validateUser** being selected and manipulated.

Your `else if` and `else` target **#validationUser**

The Javascript logic conditions are sound but you are not getting your expected results because you are targeting a different element in your `if` block.

Comment: Which is clearly a typo and hence should be closed as off topic (_"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**"_)

Comment: Would it have been better if I had added this answer after the stream of comments?